# Does Ansible execute all tasks at once or does it do a foreach?

Tags: ansible

Let's say I have a simple playbook that starts 'multiple services' up

```
- hosts: test
  tasks:
   - name: service activation 
     service: 
       name: {{ item }}
     with_item: 
      - spooler 
      - IIS Admin Service
     register: result

   - name: Service Running
     debug:
       msg: Service isn't Running
     when: result.state != running
```

One service is running and the other isn't, therefore the 'result' variable will look like the following for each service

```
spooler 

"state": "running"

IIS Admin Service

"state": "stopped"
```

I'm getting an error on the 'Service Running' step since the statuses differ between the two and it's not looping through it. Is there a way you can loop through this part? Maybe using this instead, so the variable is specific to the hostname when printed?

```
 - name: when condition example
     debug:
       msg: Service isn't Running
     when: {{ ansible_hostname }}.state != running
```

Comment: Please read [registering variable with a loop](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_loops.html#registering-variables-with-a-loop)

Answer (score 2):

Instead of just `result`, access its `.results` (I suggest you change the variable name to avoid the confusion). `service_result.results` will contain a list of dictionaries for each of our original items.

e.g.(untested):

```
- hosts: test
  tasks:
   - name: service activation 
     service: 
       name: {{ item }}
     with_items: 
      - spooler 
      - IIS Admin Service
     register: service_result

   - name: Service Running
     debug:
       msg: "Service {{item.item.name}} running: {{item.stdout}}"
     with_items: "{{ service_result.results }}"
```

You can find more information in [the official documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_loops.html#registering-variables-with-a-loop). Also note that the `loop` keyword is [preferred](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_loops.html) over `with_items` syntax.

Comment: How do I loop through the following in my debug step? I keep getting errors. These are just two of the many values i get back

`u'display_name': u'IceWarp POP3 / IMAP', u'name': u'MerakPOP3' `

Code I'm using
`- name: service activation 
    win_service: 
      name: "{{ item }}"
    with_items: 
    - MerakPOP3
    - MerakControl
    register: service_result
  - name: Service Running
    debug:
      msg: "Service ({{ item.name }})"
    loop: "{{ service_result.results }}"`

Comment: to get `item.name` within the iteration you cannot use `item.name`, that item refers to each registered result, not the original item. To access the name of original item you can use `item.item.name` (as in my example code)

Answer (score 0):

Given the registered variable *out*

```yaml
    - service:
        name: "{{ item }}"
      loop:
        - ssh
        - ufw
        - xen
      register: out
```

Declare the dictionary

```yaml
  service_state: "{{ dict(out.results|json_query('[].[item, status.SubState]')) }}"
```

gives for example,

```yaml
  service_state:
    ssh: running
    ufw: exited
    xen: exited
```

Now, you can create any report you want. For example,

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "Service {{ item.key }} isn't running. State = {{ item.value }}"
      loop: "{{ service_state|dict2items|selectattr('value', 'ne', 'running') }}"
```

gives (abridged)

```yaml
  msg: Service ufw isn't running. State = exited
  msg: Service xen isn't running. State = exited
```

---

- Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  become: true
  connection: local

  vars:

    service_state: "{{ dict(out.results|json_query('[].[item, status.SubState]')) }}"

  tasks:

    - service:
        name: "{{ item }}"
      loop:
        - ssh
        - ufw
        - xen
      register: out

    - debug:
        var: service_state

    - debug:
        msg: "Service {{ item.key }} isn't running. State = {{ item.value }}"
      loop: "{{ service_state|dict2items|selectattr('value', 'ne', 'running') }}"
```

- You can select any attributes you want. For example,

```yaml
  fieldnames: [service, load, enabled, state]
  service_state: "{{ out.results|
                     json_query('[].{service: item,
                                     load: status.LoadState,
                                     enabled: status.UnitFilePreset,
                                     state: status.SubState}') }}"
```

gives the list

```yaml
  service_state:
    - {enabled: enabled, load: loaded, service: ssh, state: running}
    - {enabled: enabled, load: loaded, service: ufw, state: exited}
    - {enabled: enabled, load: loaded, service: xen, state: exited}
```

Write it to a CSV file

```yaml
    - copy:
        dest: /tmp/selected_services_status.csv
        content: |
          {{ fieldnames|join(';') }}
          {% for i in service_state %}
          {{ fieldnames|map('extract', i)|join(';') }}
          {% endfor %}
```

gives

```bash
shell> cat /tmp/selected_services_status.csv 
service;load;enabled;state
ssh;loaded;enabled;running
ufw;loaded;enabled;exited
xen;loaded;enabled;exited
```